# How does Matlab Simulink run blocks in it simultaneously?

Tags: multithreading, matlab, simulink

Actually, my question is very simple. I try to understand how Matlab Simulink runs blocks in it simultaneously. And when I generate code with Embedded Coder, generated code does not include any multithreading function or header file. That confused me.

Thank you in advance

Comment: It does not run blocks simulatneously, it simulates each time "step" one by one, as you would in a for loop. Simulink is just a fancy way to write for loops with complex models, but its just all normal code.

Comment: As I understand from you, It run codes sequential. Right? So what order does it run the blocks? Do we know which block run first?

Comment: It doesn't matter. It simulates 1 time step at a time. That time step may have 1 or 10000 blocks, its irrelevant in which order they are simulated. It doesn't take the output of one block and give it to the next, it just saves it to use in the next time step.

Comment: @AnderBiguri that's not right - a simple block like a "gain" block does indeed pass on its output in the same time step. Something like a unit delay block is required to break any "algebraic loops". https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/algebraic-loops.html . This comment box is far too small to cover this topic though...

Comment: @Edric ah, absolutely, you are right. But the ones that don't store it for later are because they don't have a "sequentially breaking out of order execution" feature, if that makes any sense. I overly simplified it in my comment, but I think OP was a bit further away from understanding than "algebaric loops" so I simplfied. Perhaps too much, I appreciate your comment.

Comment: You can view the execution order of the blocks see https://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/controlling-and-displaying-the-sorted-order.html